# Adjusting Density Plot Color Function for Diffraction Simulation

Tags: color, visualization, physics

I'm trying to simulate Fraunhofer diffraction by a single slit using `DensityPlot`

I run the code:

```
DensityPlot[(Sinc[β])^2, {β, -6 π, 6 π}, {y, -6 π, 6 π}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
           ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, AspectRatio -> 9/16, Frame :> False]
```

and get:

[image]

Which is great but I'd like the coloring to be based on a red scale so that the "lightest" areas are bright red which corresponds to a 632.8 nm He-Ne Laser. The following image shows the type of red scale I'd like to mimic:
[image: Red]

Thanks

Comment: Great, I have found both of your suggestions to be very helpful. Thank You

Answer (score 12):

First take a sample of the real image to get the right color mix:

```
ii = Import@"http://tsgphysics.mit.edu/pics/Q%20Diffraction/Q2-Single-Slit-Diffraction.jpg";
h = ImageTake[ii, {366, 402}, {373, 543}]
hd = Transpose[(ImageData@h)[[IntegerPart[ImageDimensions[h][[2]]/2]]]];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let's see the color curves. It's easy to see that the Red channel is the triple of the Blue and Green:

```
GraphicsRow@{ListLinePlot[hd], ListLinePlot[{1, 3, 3} hd]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So now we can build up a "correct" simulation:

```
Manipulate[
          t0 = ConstantArray[Table[Min[1, a   Sinc[x]^2], {x, -6 π, 6 π, .1}], {100}];
          t1 = ConstantArray[Table[Min[1, a/3 Sinc[x]^2], {x, -6 π, 6 π, .1}], {100}];
          ColorCombine[{Image@t0, Image@t1, Image@t1}, "RGB"], 
{a, 5, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 9):

This is a pragmatic approach, possibly if you understand more about light and lasers, you could do way better. I just use trial and error, with "manual" `Blend`:

```
DensityPlot[(Sinc[\[Beta]])^2, {\[Beta], -6 \[Pi], 6 \[Pi]}, {y, -6 \[Pi], 6 \[Pi]},
    PlotPoints -> 200, 
    ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{0, Black}, {1/3, Red}, {0.4, White}}, #] &), 
    AspectRatio -> 9/16, Frame :> False]
```

[image]

To get a better feeling, try:

```
Manipulate[
   DensityPlot[(Sinc[\[Beta]])^2, {\[Beta], -6 \[Pi], 6 \[Pi]}, {y, -6 \[Pi], 6 \[Pi]},      
       PlotPoints -> 200, 
       ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{0, Black}, {re, Red}, {wh, White}}, #] &),
       AspectRatio -> 9/16, Frame :> False], 
       {{re, 1/3}, 0, 1}, {{wh, 0.4}, re, 1}]
```

Note that the results change a bit if you reduce `PlotPoints`.

I hope this helps in a way...